# Spring integration monitor multiple jvm using same connection

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-integration

I can monitor individual SPRING INTEGRATION applications via visualvm changing the command line parameters when starting the JVM (-Dcom.sun.....)

My application has components in multiple jvm's, each of which i can name.

I would like my operational console to connect per server to one JMX service via one port. Then as I add JVM's(services) they are discoverable by the operational console(lets assume its visualvm) by name.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) I believe a single client can connect to multiple agents (you install a jolokia agent on each JVM).